# Error feeding numpy array d.type uint8 into adaptivethreshold function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, python-mss

I'm trying to feed a numpy array into the `Process_img (adaptivethreshold)` function. The numpy array has a data type of `uint8` and `3 dimensions`, which should be accepted by the function.

I am getting the following error message. I've tried converting it to `grayscale` but doesn't seem to work and i've tried `numpy.ndarray.flatten` `(1 dimension)`, which gets it functioning but doesn't display it back correctly.

I end up getting a long gray bar. I'm not sure of what else i should do. Any help is appreciated.

> error: OpenCV(3.4.4)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1524:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function
>   'cv::adaptiveThreshold'

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

# Attempts to change the image to black and white relative to a general area
def process_img(image):
    processed_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
    return processed_img

while (True):
    last_time = time.time()

    # Takes a snapshot of the screen location
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 960, "height": 540}  

    # Converts the snapshot to a numpy array    
        npm = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

    # Checks the data type of the numpy array
    print (npm.dtype)

    # Feeds the numpy array into the "process_img" function
    new_screen = process_img(npm)

    # Displays the processed image
    cv2.imshow('Window',new_screen)                  

    #This keeps the screen displayed over time instead of flickering 1ms basically the screen's refresh rate
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):           
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Can you use `print npm.shape` before `process_img(npm)`

Comment: I doubt that `mss` captures screenshots in grayscale, and since you feed the image directly to `adaptiveThreshold` it's quite likely you're not satisfying the requirement for the input image to be single channel (grayscale). | Number of dimensions of the `ndarray` and the number of channels it holds are different things. | Having tried the script locally, `npm` is actually a 4 channel image (BGRA)... `new_screen = process_img(cv2.cvtColor(npm, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))` and problem's fixed... not sure what you meant by "doesn't seem to work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `process_img()` function to convert the image to grayscale:

```
def process_img(image):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
    return cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
```

Also, you should move `with mss.mss() as sct:` outside the `while` to keep performant:

```
import time

import cv2
import mss
import numpy


# Attempts to change the image to black and white relative to a general area
def process_img(image):
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
    return cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Takes a snapshot of the screen location
    monitor = {"top": 40, "left": 0, "width": 960, "height": 540}

    while True:
        last_time = time.time()

        # Converts the snapshot to a numpy array
        npm = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Checks the data type of the numpy array
        print(npm.dtype)

        # Feeds the numpy array into the "process_img" function
        new_screen = process_img(npm)

        # Displays the processed image
        cv2.imshow("Window", new_screen)

        # This keeps the screen displayed over time instead of flickering 1ms basically the screen's refresh rate
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: Little reminder: [stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if the answer is good for you :)